<?php wp_head(); ?> and <meta property="og:title"
I'm a newbie in wordpress, I have made a site.
All works well, except for this:
when I try to share my homepage in social the preview was strange only a name call HOME and a "[" in the description,
then I have made a view source of my homepage and i have see this code:
<meta name='robots' content='index, follow, max-image-preview:large, max-snippet:-1, max-video-preview:-1' />
<meta property="og:title" content="HOME"/>
<meta property="og:description" content="["/>
<meta property="og:type" content="website"/>
<meta name="twitter:card" content="summary">
<meta name="twitter:title" content="HOME"/>
<meta name="twitter:description" content="["/>
<meta name="author" content="xxxx"/>

I search on in head.php file in the theme, then I have edit it and there is a php string (php wp_head();) that print this strange code with so meta tag.
The question is: how can I remove the printed code, I can't delete the string or all the site broke the themplate :=)
thanks in advice :)
p.s. if I watch the source code of an article all work fine, is only the homepage the problem.

Which seo plugin are you using?

If it's a [ maybe your home page is starting with a shortcode?
